# POST to external form that has reCAPTCHA

Tags: html, forms, post, recaptcha

I'm using a cloud CRM service that has a web form functionality, but the design of the form is limited.
I'm trying to create a custom http form that POST to the original form.

```
<form method="POST" action="//externalForm.Url/path">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <textarea name="message"></textarea></div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
</form>
```

The problem is, the form uses reCAPTCHA, so I couldn't do this.
Would it help if I had reCAPTCHA in my form?
what should I do?

Comment: To be blunt, this is exactly why reCAPTCHA exists -- to prevent form hijacking like this. You'll also potentially face cross-site issues here. Does the CRM have a web service or a different API? You could create your custom form, post to your own server-side application, and forward the data to the CRM system with said service or API.

Answer (score 0):

If your cloud CRM service has a CRUD API you can post by way of Webservice via the server or even on the front-end, but because of security reasons you wont be able to recreate the exact form action on your server and simply post to theirs.